# How to check if MySql database column is Empty not NULL but only blank

Tags: php, mysql

This is what my database look like

[image]

my code is

```
if(($rate!==NULL || $rate!=="")==true){
          $count2=$count2+15;
        } else if(($rate==NULL)==true){
          $count2=$count2+0;
        }
```

my problem is its keep reading that the column is having a value while it had blank not a white space and also not null. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
if(!is_null($rate) || $rate != "") {
    $count2 += 15;
} elseif(is_null($rate)) {
    //I think you can remove this line and the elseif
    //$count2 += 0;
}
```

Comment: empty isn't reliable for this. if `$rate` is a natural `0`, that still counts as `empty()` to php.